# Openshift Patching Pod Via Rest

Tags: openshift

I am trying to see how I can patch a Pod for OpenShift Via Rest by following the  [OpenShift Pod-Patch Rest Documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/rest_api/api/v1.Pod.html#Patch-api-v1-namespaces-namespace-pods-name). I have been able to post data with other apis from OpenShift such as Secret.

If I do curl call just to update the metadata name of a given pod:

`curl -k \
    -X PATCH \
    -d @- \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' \
    $OPENSHIFT_URL/api/v1/namespaces/mytestproject/pods/app-1-build << 'EOF'
    {
    "kind": "Pod",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "app-2-build"
      }
    }
EOF`

I get the response:

`{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type jsonpatch.Patch",
  "code": 500
}`

I am unable to figure out what I am doing incorrect based on the schema, and the documentation at OpenShift for pod does not show examples of the [json data schema](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/rest_api/api/v1.Pod.html#object-schema) in curl examples.

Comment: That isn't correct format for JSON patch. Did you first work out how to do it using the ``oc patch --type=json`` command? If have that working, use ``--loglevel=9`` option to have it show what it sent to the REST API. Also, if you are using DeploymentConfig, you shouldn't be patching the Pod directly, you should patch the Pod template in the DeploymentConfig.

Comment: I was able to figure it out by your loglevel suggestion with the cli tool. It was the DeploymentConfig.